# How can I select few columns with MAX(column) from several grouped columns?

Tags: sql

My table has a lot of columns, I didn't list them all at here.
But the selected columns are like below:

| product_line | test_port | rate1 | rate2 | test_stage | finished_time | update_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| phone | A | 50 | 50 | final | 2022-04-20 12:00:00 | 2022-04-20 10:50:30 |
| phone | A | 10 | 10 | final | 2022-04-20 12:00:00 | 2022-04-20 11:51:20 |
| phone | A | 80 | 90 | final | 2022-04-25 12:00:00 | 2022-04-25 11:20:11 |
| computer | A | 70 | 75 | init | 2022-04-25 12:00:00 | 2022-04-25 11:30:45 |
| computer | B | 90 | 80 | init | 2022-04-25 12:00:00 | 2022-04-25 11:56:22 |

When I select these columns, I need group by "product_line, test_port, test_stage, finished_time", **sadly also rate1 rate2.**

But all I need unique together is the combination of **"product_line, test_port, test_stage, finished_time"**.

I have to find the latest(max) row of **update_dt** that is grouped by **"product_line, test_port, test_stage, finished_time"**.
The result I need is like:

| product_line | test_port | rate1 | rate2 | test_stage | finished_time | max(update_dt) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| phone | A | 10 | 10 | final | 2022-04-20 12:00:00 | 2022-04-20 11:51:20 |
| phone | A | 80 | 90 | final | 2022-04-25 12:00:00 | 2022-04-25 11:20:11 |
| computer | A | 70 | 75 | init | 2022-04-25 12:00:00 | 2022-04-25 11:30:45 |
| computer | B | 90 | 80 | init | 2022-04-25 12:00:00 | 2022-04-25 11:56:22 |

I'm stucking at the part that SQL asking me add rate1, rate2 to the group by.

---

update my answer 2022/04/27

```
with cte as
(
    SELECT product_line, test_port, test_stage, finished_time, max(update_dt) as latest_update
    FROM table
    GROUP BY product_line, test_port, test_stage, finished_time
)
select cte.product_line, tmp.rate1, tmp.rate2, cte.test_port, cte.test_stage, cte.finished_time, cte.latest_update
from cte left join (
    SELECT DISTINCT
    product_line, test_port, rate1, rate2, test_stage, finish_time, updated_at as latest_update
    FROM table_a
    ) as tmp
on cte.product_line = tmp.product_line 
AND cte.test_port = tmp.test_port AND cte.test_stage = tmp.test_stage 
AND cte.finished_time = tmp.finished_time AND cte.latest_update=tmp.latest_update
```

Comment: Johan B's CTE method is valid. But need change a little bit. The JOIN columns also need include the cte.max_update_dr = a.update_dt.

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
SELECT product_line, test_port, test_stage, finished_time, max(update_dt)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY product_line, test_port, test_stage, finished_time
```

If you wanna add the rate columns

```
with cte as
(
    SELECT product_line, test_port, test_stage, finished_time, max(update_dt) as max_update_dr
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY product_line, test_port, test_stage, finished_time
)
select cte.product_line, a.rate1, a.rate2, cte.test_port, cte.test_stage, cte.finished_time, cte.max_update_dr
from cte left join your_table a
on cte.product_line = a.product_line, cte.test_port = a.test_port, cte.test_stage = a-test_stage, cte.finished_time = a.finished_time
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify the rows you want. Then, filtering is easy. For example:

```
select *
from (
  select
    t.*,
    row_number() over(
      partition by product_line, test_port, test_stage, finished_time
      order by updated_dt desc
    ) as rn
  from t
) x
where rn = 1
```